# Gad and Reuven exiled eight years before everyone else

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, mattos

Bamidbar Rabbah [22:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Bemidbar_Rabbah.22.7?lang=bi), Eichah Rabbah [Pesikta 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah%2C_Petichta.5?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=he), Midrash Tanchumah [Mattos 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Matot.5.1?vhe=Tsel_Midrash_Tanchuma&lang=he), Tanchumah Yashan [Mattos 8](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Matot.8?vhe=Midrash_Tanhuma_haKadum_veHaYashan,_S._Buber,_1885&lang=he) all point out that the tribes of Gad and Reuven, because they chose to live outside the land of Israel proper, were exiled before their brothers.

The Ba'al HaTurim to [Numbers 32:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Baal_Haturim_on_Numbers.32.1.1?lang=he) notes that Gad and Reuven are mentioned eight times in the parsha where they request this land, to hint to the **eight years** they were exiled before everyone else. I also saw the Chida [quotes](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_David%2C_Numbers%2C_Matot.8?vhe=Penei_David_--_Torat_Emet&lang=he) [Rabbeinu Efraim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92) as saying the same thing. The above midrashim don't mention eight years; what is the source that it was specifically eight years?

Comment: See [Rashi to Isaiah 8:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.8.23?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Isaiah.8.23&lang2=bi). Sourced from the notes from the ArtScroll Ba'al Haturim.

Comment: @Salmonius2 if you explain that Rashi it could be a great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rashi on Yeshaya 8:23 says-

> כי לא מועף לאשר מוצק לה. כי מלך אשור אשר ניתן למוצק ולהצר לה לארצכם אינו עיף ואינו עצל מלבא עליהם עד שלש פעמים אחת בימי פקח (מלכים ב ט״ו:כ״ט) אשר לקח את עיון ואת אבל מעכה ואת קדש ואת הגליל כל ארץ נפתלי והגלות ההיא בשנת ד' לאחז ובשנת שתים עשרה ויער אלהי ישראל את רוח פול מלך אשור ויגלם לראובני ולגדי ולחצי שבט המנשה מקרא זה (בדברי הימי' א ה') וגלות זה בשנת שתים עשרה לאחז תחלת מרדו של הושע בן אלה כענין שנאמר (מלכים ב י״ז:ד׳) וימצא מלך אשור בהושע קשר וגו' לאחר שנשתעבד לו שמנה שנה ואין החשבון מפורש במקרא בגלוי אבל יש ללמוד מברייתא דסדר עולם והשלישית בשנת שש לחזקיה שנת תשע למרדו של הושע אשר נלכדה שומרון היא עיר המלוכה וגלו כולם וזה האמור כאן כי לא עיפות לאויב אשר הוא מוצק לה לארץ ישראל האמורה בעניין ואל ארץ יביט:

> For if there were to be any break of day for that [land] which is in straits: Because the king of Assyria, who was given permission to distress your land, is not too tired nor too lazy to come to them even three times... "And in the twelfth year (of Achaz's reign) God woke the spirit of Pul king of Assyria, and he expelled the tribes of Reuven, Gad, and half of Mennashe." This Passuk, and this exile, was during Achaz's twelfth year as king, which was the **beginning of Hoshea Ben Alla's rebellion**... After he served **for eight years**. And the math isn't explicitly in the Pessukim, but it can be learned from the Braita of Seder Olam. And the third (exile) was ... During the **ninth year of Hoshea's rebellion**, in which the capital city Shomron was captured, and everyone was exiled...

(Translation and bold are by me)

Comment: This answer is accredited to, in part, @Salmononius2 for the link.